# I want to init mikroConfig to MikroORM with typescript and i got this error message

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mikro-orm

### The error message:

Argument of type '{ readonly entities: readonly [typeof Post]; readonly dbName: "lireddit"; readonly type: "postgresql"; readonly debug: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Configuration<IDatabaseDriver> | Options<IDatabaseDriver> | undefined'.
Type '{ readonly entities: readonly [typeof Post]; readonly dbName: "lireddit"; readonly type: "postgresql"; readonly debug: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Options<IDatabaseDriver>'.
Type '{ readonly entities: readonly [typeof Post]; readonly dbName: "lireddit"; readonly type: "postgresql"; readonly debug: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<MikroORMOptions<IDatabaseDriver>>'.
Types of property 'entities' are incompatible.
The type 'readonly [typeof Post]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(string | EntityClass<AnyEntity> | EntityClassGroup<AnyEntity> | EntitySchema<any, undefined>)[]'.ts(2345)

### The index.ts:

```
import { MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { __prod__ } from './constants';
import { Post } from './entities/Post';
import mikroConfig from './mikro-orm.config';

const main = async() => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(mikroConfig);
    const post = orm.em.create(Post, {title:'ez az első posztom hehe'})
    await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post)
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

### And the mikro-orm.config.ts:

```
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";

export default {
    entities:[Post],
    dbName: "lireddit",
    type: "postgresql",
    debug : !__prod__,
} as const;
```

Thank you for the help i you can, its so painful

Comment: From Ben Awad's "Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial." https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8?t=1499 Thank you for posting - I was getting tripped up on this as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

2023 update - there is a `defineConfig` helper nowadays, which is better suited:

```
// import it from your driver package and you 
// won't need to provide the `type` or `driver` option
import { defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/postgresql';
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";

export default defineConfig({
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: "lireddit",
//  type: "postgresql", not needed with `defineConfig()`
    debug : !__prod__,
});
```

---

The way you are defining your ORM config is wrong, you should use `Options` type from the core package instead of const assertion. Define the config this way to have the best intellisense support (as well as to get rid of that TS error):

```
import { Options } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";

const config: Options = {
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: "lireddit",
    type: "postgresql",
    debug : !__prod__,
};
export default config;
```

Comment: I try this, but I can't get the syntax to accept the 'as Parameters' extension to the const: eg below

import { Options, MikroOrm } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";

const config: Options =  {
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: "testlireddit",
    type: "postgresql",
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
} as Parameters<typeof MikroOrm.init>;

export default config;

Comment: I also get an error when i defin the const in this way. the feedback is: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Options<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Pick<MikroORMOptions<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>, "type" | "driver" | "namingStrategy" | "implicitTransactions" | "timezone" | "useBatchInserts" | "useBatchUpdates" | ... 12 more ... | "multipleStatements">'

Comment: You should use neither `as const` nor `as Parameters`. Are you actually trying what my answer says? None of that is present in there. All you need is just `Options` type.

Comment: Thanks, Ben's lireddit tutorial explains the upside of the Parameters tag

Comment: My answer here tells you how it should be done. I am the author of the ORM so I hope I know better than Ben, his tutorial actually did a lot of harm to the library as he did not fully understand a lot of its concepts.

Comment: Thanks Martin Adámek, works perfectly. Could you point where in the mikro-orm docs this typing with { Options } is? I can't seem to find it. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinAdámek Thank you for this Martin. It helped me as well. If you could separately clarify what was wrong with Ben's tutorial - I would be appreciative. Only as I wish to learn, and this is at least a resource to get me started, but if you could clarify any pitfalls, well, it would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MartinAdámek It works fine for me. I will say using config: Option is a nice upgrade to Ben's tutorial.